# Calculate First answer from user and ignore others, by Using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

If a User attempt a question more than one time then i want to sum only first answer in the total and want to ignore other answers of same question, how can we do that by using eloquent method. Right now i am using following code that calculate all values included repeated answers. How can we subtract repeated answers from total?

```
$total_score = User::find($user->id)->testsresult->sum('correct');
```

Below is database structure

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you want to sum? the test result of a user or the number of correct answers?

Comment: i want to sum correct answers but want to ignore repeated answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy()` to get `distinct` sum

```
$total_score = User::find($user->id)->testsresult()->groupBy('option_id')->get()->sum('correct');
```